# Resource not found - dx:ASPxDocumentViewer - only on development machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, devexpress

The issue I describe here affects only my development machine. Deploying to different servers (Test and Production) do not exhibit this behaviour.

I have a simple ASPX (ReportViswer.aspx) page that contains a DevExpress Report Viewer in it as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteV2.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportViewer.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyApp.Platform.Reports.ReportViewer" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v16.1.Web, Version=16.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<asp:Content ID="cntPageTabs" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphPageTabs" runat="server">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#tab-page" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" class="myapp-ctrl-noprogress">Page</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content tab-content-for-page">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-page">
            <asp:Button ID="btnToolbarClose" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnToolbarClose_OnClick"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMainContent" runat="server">
    <dx:ASPxDocumentViewer ID="ReportDocumentViewer" runat="server"></dx:ASPxDocumentViewer>
</asp:Content>
```

The page itself does nothing really clever other than instantiating an XtraReport and assigning it to the report viewer:

```
protected void Page_Load(object aSender, EventArgs aEventArgs)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["ReportParams"] == null)
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("No report information was passed.");
            return;
        }
        ReportParametersHelper reportParams = new ReportParametersHelper();
        reportParams.Deserialize(Session["ReportParams"].ToString());

        XtraReport reportToView = null;

        switch (reportParams.ReportName)
        {
            case ReportNames.REPORT_DISCOVERY_DOCUMENT:
                reportToView = new ReportDiscoveryDocument();

                (reportToView as ReportEmailMessage).Activate(ReportParams.Params);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The WebForms 4.6.1 solution is running against IIS 10 on Windows 10 on my development machine and when I try and open the above page via a simple **Response.Redirect(~/reports/reportviewer)** I either get prompted for a username and password:

[image]

or ultimately a resource not found error:

[image]

The application is running against the DefaultApp pool that is configured as:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Why does this work on production and staging and not on my development machine (ie ReportViewer displays just fine with no issue)
2. Is there perhaps a correlation with the fact that IIS things this page is .NET 2.x? (see screenshot)
3. Any ideas on how to debug this? I cannot develop reports on this machine.

DevExpress has been unhelpful as they want a small sample project - and while I understand that the test harnesses do not exhibit this behaviour so it is something in this much larger project.

So any insights or ideas would be appreciated and I am happy to provide more diagnostics information as required.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely caused by your development machine routing settings rather then by DevExpress components. If this is the case, you will be able to reproduce it even if you remove the ASPxDocumentViewer control from your WebForm.

Try passing the following route format to your Response.Redirect method "~/reports/reportviewer.aspx". This is the default ASP.NET WebForms route format, and when you are using the "~/reports/reportviewer" IIS attempts to open the folder rather then a web page, so the authorization is requested and 404 error is thrown. This issue is not reproducible on another machines because of different routing settings.
 
See the [ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) MSDN article for more information on how routing works in ASP.NET.

Comment: The above suggestion made no difference unfortunately.